# Swift how to fill in overlay with a new color

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, overlay, fill

I am having trouble filling in the overlay.  I would like to use a new color.  Thanks for the help in advance.

```
func addBoundry()
    {
        var points=[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.02, -76.9),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.97, -76.9),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.97, -77),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.02, -77)]

        let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)

        mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
    }

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
                                                                  regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        if overlay is MKPolygon {
            let polygonView = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            //polygonView.strokeColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
            polygonView.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 180/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 0.4)

            return polygonView
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an outline to your polygon with `strokeColor`, you have to set `lineWidth` for your `MKPolygonRenderer`. The default value is `0`.

But, you say "filling in the overlay". If your intent was to fill it in, you'd use `fillColor`, not `strokeColor`.

(Of course, I'd also make sure that you've specified the `delegate` of the map view, properly and that your `rendererForOverlay` is getting called at all. Add a breakpoint and/or log statement in there and make sure that routine is getting called properly.)

Answer (score 0):

The overlay view can be filled by using the delegate method of MKMapView.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay{

    MKPolylineView *overlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    overlayView.lineWidth = 5;

    if ([overlay.title isEqualToString:@"other"]){
        overlayView.strokeColor= [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        overlayView.fillColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    else if([overlay.title isEqualToString:@"one"]){
        overlayView.strokeColor= [UIColor blueColor];
        overlayView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }

    return overlayView;

}
```